# Pip error when trying to install module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to install PyDrive [a wrapper library of the google drive api for python] and pip is giving me this error. It did the same thing when trying to install things like matplotlib or mega.py [a mega.nz api for python].

Here's the error:
[image]

Anyone got a clue what's going on?

Cheers

Comment: I tried pip.exe too but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: use pip3 since you are using python 3.x

Comment: It's strange that `pip.py` is in `c:\python34`

Comment: @joelgoldstick https://i.gyazo.com/e5f8327e2849fd805cf16fda4ff7851e.png

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you rename `pip.py` to something else and then try it?  On my system (also Windows), there is no `pip.py` in Scripts, only `pip.exe`.  It seems possible that pip is trying to do `import pip` but is getting the script instead of the library.

Comment: @BrenBarn What you said is confusing. Are you saying pip.exe is not importing pip.py?

Comment: @iPhynx: There is a library called `pip` somewhere on your system (and it may also be bundled within `pip.exe`).  That is different from the "entry point" script that actually runs pip from the command line.  When you run pip, it will try to import the library called `pip`.  If there is a script called `pip.py` in the Scripts directory (representing the entry-point script, not the library), it may import that instead of the real library.  If this is indeed the problem, renaming `pip.py` to something else will remove the name conflict and allow pip to properly import the library it needs.

Comment: @BrenBarn That worked great, thanks! I renamed it and it worked right away. Post that as an answer and I'll pick at as solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try renaming that `pip.py` to something else.

There is a library called pip somewhere on your system (and it may also be bundled within pip.exe). That is different from the "entry point" script that actually runs pip from the command line. When you run pip, it will try to import the library called pip. If there is a script called pip.py in the Scripts directory (representing the entry-point script, not the library), it may import that instead of the real library. If this is indeed the problem, renaming pip.py to something else will remove the name conflict and allow pip to properly import the library it needs.

I'm not sure how you wound up with pip.py in your Scripts directory in the first place.  I don't think it should be there.  My Python installation on Windows doesn't have it.

Comment: @iPhynx note also that there is a newer version of PyDrive on GitHub which has support for Py3 among other things. Check out the updated [docs](https://github.com/googledrive/PyDrive#pydrive).